# Определить номер столбца прямоугольной матрицы, в котором число элементов, больших М, минимально

Tags: pascal

У меня такая задача:
Определить номер столбца прямоугольной матрицы, в котором число элементов, больших М, минимально.
При этом нужно параметры матрицы ввести с клавиатуры, а заполнить ее случайным образом.
Далее, в функции нужно реализовать как раз основную задачу программы - сравнить элементы в столбце, найти сколько элементов в нем больше переменной М, сделать тоже самое с другими столбцами и сравнить в итоге, где число элементов, больших М, минимально.

Ввод матрицы и вывод ее на экран у меня получилось сделать, не без помощи пользователей #ХэшКод :) Вот здесь можете посмотреть, если кому интересно [здесь](http://bit.ly/zaDKBS)

Теперь не соображу, как сделать так, чтобы стало возможным работать с элементами массива именно по столбцам в функции, где будет происходить как раз именно их сравнение с переменной M по столбцам.

Думаю, что нужно добавить одномерный массив, в который будут копироваться значения из столбцов.

Что скажите?

Вот код, что у меня получается. Пока что застопорилась на функции.

```
program zadanie;

uses crt;

const a = 10; {dlya zadaniya strok matricij}
      b = 10; {dlya zadaniya stolbcov matricij}

type  mass = array [1..a, 1..b] of integer;
      stolbcij_matricij = array [1..b] of integer; {dlya zapisi znachenij
                                                    elementov stolbcov v
                                                    otdelnyu matricy}

var   matr : mass;              {dlya obsheij matricij}
      stolb: stolbcij_matricij; {dlya zapisi znachenij stolbcov}
      m    : integer;           {znachenie dlya sravneniya}
      a1,b1  : integer;         {dlya opredeleniya parametrov matricij}

{*********************************************************************}

procedure vvod_matricij; {procedyra dlya vivoda matricij na ekran}

var i,j:integer;

begin
   writeln('Vvedite a: ');
   readln(a1);

   writeln('Vvedite b: ');
   readln(b1);

   randomize;
   for i:=1 to a do
   begin
      for j:=1 to b do
         begin
            matr[i,j]:=random(10);
         end;
   end;

end;

{*********************************************************************}

procedure matrica_na_ekrane;

   var i,j : integer;

      begin
         for i:=1 to a1 do
            begin
               for j:=1 to b1 do
               begin
                  write(matr[i,j]:5);
               end;
               writeln;writeln;
            end;
      end;
{*********************************************************************}

function stolbec:integer;
   var m : integer;           {peremennaya dlya sravneniya}
       j : integer;           {znacheniya elementov v stolbcah}
       kolichestvo : integer; {peremennaya dlya podscheta
                               kolichestva chisel bolshih, chem m}

   begin
      write('Vvedite peremennyu M: ');
      readln(m);

      kolichestvo := 0;

   end;

{*********************************************************************}

BEGIN
   clrscr;

   vvod_matricij;
   matrica_na_ekrane;
   stolbec;

   readln;
END.
```

Что делать дальше?

Comment: В процедуре `vvod_matricij` в циклах вместо `a` и `b` должны быть `a1` и `b1`, хотя это не очень влияет на заполнение матрицы.

    for i:=1 to a1 do
    begin
       for j:=1 to b1 do
          begin
             matr[i,j]:=random(10);
          end;
    end;

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Зачем копировать в отдельный массив?

```
{Не забыть обнулить массив `kol` в этом месте}
for i := 1 to a do
  for j := 1 to b do
     if matr[i, j] > M then {элементы матрицы большие M}
       inc(kol[j]);         {посчитаем в каждом столбце}
{и найдем минимум}
answer := 1;
for j := 2 to b do
  if kol[j] < kol[answer] then
    answer := j;
{answer - искомый номер столбца}
```

Без массива `kol`

```
answer := 1;
min := maxlongint;
for j := 1 to b do
begin
  kol := 0;
  for i := 1 to a do
     if matr[i, j] > M then {элементы матрицы большие M}
       inc(kol);         {посчитаем}
  {и найдем минимум}
  if kol < min then
  begin
    answer := j;
    min := kol;
  end;
end;
```

Comment: а можно комментарии написать в коде, если не сложно? а то, что-то я не совсем разобралась:)

Comment: @elenavictory обновил ответ

Comment: inc() - это функция, я правильно поняла?

Comment: `inc(i)` тоже самое, что и `i := i + 1`, но быстрее (по идее)

Comment: а answer в данном случае переменная? почему нужно присваивать ей единицу?

и куда сохраняется количество элементов, после того, как посчитается? в kol[j] ?

может быть, глупый вопрос, но...

Comment: куда сохраняется посчитанное количество элементов в каждом столбце, больших М? В kol[j] ?

Comment: да, answer - это переменная. Чем еще кроме переменной `answer` может быть?

Comment: Можно сделать без массива kol

Comment: @insolor да

Comment: @insolor, как можно сделать без массива kol?

Comment: @elenavictory обновил ответ

Comment: как же мне хочется хорошо программировать:)

все задаю и задаю глупые вопросы...

стараюсь:) {и в смысле задания вопросов и в смысле изучения программирования:) }

Comment: @Андрей, что такое min := maxlongint; ?

Comment: Это нужно для того, чтобы `min` был больше `kol` при первом проходе (когда `j = 1`). Также прочитайте комментарий к ответу insolor.

Answer (score 2):

Без массива kol (здесь kol просто integer):

```
  for j := 1 to b do
  begin
    {подсчитываем в текущем столбце:}
    kol := 0;
    for i:=1 to a do 
      if matr[i, j] > M then
        inc(kol);

    {если столбец первый, то считаем, что в нем минимальное количество}
    {а если не первый, то сравниваем текущее количество с минимальным количеством:}
    if (j=1) or (kol<minkol) then 
    begin
      minkol := kol;
      answer := j;
    end;
  end;
```

Comment: `minkol` нужно задать правильное начальное значение, если это локальная переменная в функции или процедуре, то там мусор, возможно отрицательный. Или

Comment: if (j=1) or ... then 
    begin
      minkol := kol;

Comment: признаю, я сглупил